# Уведомления срабатывают не на всех устройствах, notification и AlarmManager

Tags: android, уведомления

Друзья, я не давно начал на андроид писать и опять у меня вопрос по уведомлениям, сделал по примерам, работает на всех эмуляторах, а у пользователя, как минимум одного вместо срабатывания блымкает экран и все, уведомление не возникает, 7 версии андроид, в настройках уведомления разрешены, в чем может быть косяк? Посмотрите код плиз

В фрагменте устанавливаю время срабатывания:

```
if (Core.get().getPreferences().getBoolean("reminder_drink_switch",false)) {
        Intent intentWater = new Intent(getContext(), MainBaseService.class);
        intentWater.setAction(MainBaseService.ACTION_WATER_ALARM);

        PendingIntent sender2 = PendingIntent.getService(getContext(), 2, intentWater, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Core.get().getPreferences().getInt("reminderDrinkHour", 0));
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, Core.get().getPreferences().getInt("reminderDrinkMinute", 0));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

        long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl, sender2);
    }
```

В классе, где сервис

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_PROCESS_ASSET_BASE.equals(action)) {
            handleProcessAssetBase();
        } else if (ACTION_CHECK_BASE_UPDATES.equals(action)) {
            handleCheckBaseUpdates();
        } else if (ACTION_PROCESS_OLD_BASE.equals(action)) {
            handleProcessOldBase();
        } else if (ACTION_BASE_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
            handleBaseUpdate(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MAIN_BASE_URL), intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MAIN_BASE_VERSION));
        } else if (ACTION_PROCESS_BURNER_BASE.equals(action)) {
            handleProcessBurnerBase();
        } else if (ACTION_WATER_ALARM.equals(action)) {
            showWaterNotification();
        } else if (ACTION_EATINGS_ALARM.equals(action)) {
            showEatingsNotification();
        }
    }
}

private void showBackgroundNotification(int requestCode, Notification notification, Bundle extras) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST_NOTIFICATION);
    intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION, notification);
    if(extras != null) intent.putExtras(extras);
    sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, PERMISSION_PRIVATE, null, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
}

    private void showWaterNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_WATER_ID, intent, 0);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.water_notify))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_water_notify)

            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.apple64))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.water_notify)))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.water_notify))
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    boolean sleep = true;

    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try {
        Date now = new Date();
        now = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(now.getTime()));
        Date nachalo = dateFormat.parse("7:00");
        Date konec = dateFormat.parse("22:00");
        if (now.after(nachalo) && now.before(konec))
            sleep = false;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!sleep) {
        if (Core.get().getPreferences().getBoolean("vibrate", true))
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        if (Core.get().getPreferences().getBoolean("sound", true))
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    }

   showBackgroundNotification(NOTIFICATION_WATER_ID, notification, null);
}
```

Класс ресивер

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {        
    int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra(MainBaseService.REQUEST_CODE, 0);
    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainBaseService.NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    if (notification!=null)
    notificationManager.notify(requestCode, notification);
}
```

}

В манифесте есть:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<receiver
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="-999">
            <action android:name="ru.hikisoft.calories.mainBase.broadcast.NOTIFICATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Алармы - это головная боль. С каждым новым API вводят какие-то ограничения и "особенности". Например, начиная с API 19 система не гарантирует доставку аларма вовремя, а с API 23 ввели `Dozen Mode`. Ну и соответственно добавлялись новые методы установки Alarm. Вот так примерно должна выглядеть процедура установки:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
          {
            final AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, pendingIntent);
            am.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);
          }
      else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
      else
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: сам аларм похоже срабатывает и просто через set, а вот вместо уведомления у пользователя идет схлопывание текущей активити и выбрасывает в mainactivity, тестировал в генимошн у себя на компе на этих версиях андроида, все  срабатывает как надо, уведомления формируются, схлапывание не происходит

Comment: устройство при этом находится в стендбае?

Comment: нет, для теста я ей сделал вообще без задержки уведомление, пробовали и с открытым приложением и с свернутым, и с задержкой в минуту, не помогает

Comment: остается только грешить на сервис, андроид может его убить когда и как захочет. Попробуйте устанавливать аларм на ресивер, у него приоритет максимальный, ну и там уже формировать уведомления

Comment: Тогда бы поидее вообще не сработало бы ничего, а так что-то происходит, экран блымкает, активити тушится, как буд-то ошибка какая, я вот думаю может я не правильно как то с нотификациями себя веду? Вот этот момент Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainBaseService.NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    if (notification!=null)
    notificationManager.notify(requestCode, notification);

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но не срабатывал showBackgroundNotification, переделал через

```
    //  showBackgroundNotification(NOTIFICATION_WATER_ID, notification, null);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_WATER_ID, notification);
```